# Swift JsonEncoder element order

Tags: json, swift, encoding

I'm currently working on a project were the provided API sadly is a hot mess. I'm encoding a Codable with several nested Types following the first solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com) medium article about Indeterminate Types with Codable in Swift.
So, I'm using an enum to allow different types in my Codable Messages roughly as follows:

```
struct CommandBase: Encodable {
   let command: CommandType

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      let command = "c"
   }
}

enum CommandType: Encodable {
   case someCommand(someContainer)
   case someOtherCommand(someOtherContainer)

   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      switch self {
      case .someCommand(let someContainer):
         try container.encode("something", forkey: .name)
         try container.encode(someContainer, forKey: .container)
         try container.encode("etc", forKey: .etc)
      case .someOtherCommand(let someOtherContainer):
          // about the same as above case
      }

   }  

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name
      case container
      case etc
   }

}
```

The problem is, as I mentioned the API I have to work with is a mess and NEEDS the json in the correct order. But for some reason the Standard JsonEncoder always puts the .container first.

This is a refactor the earlier version used several generic types and resulted in hardly readable code but the order was met.

The JsonEncoder has an outputFormatting attribute which uses a OutputFormatting type like .sortedKeys to sort the keys alphabetical. But I don't understand if and how its possible to utilize this attribute to sort a nested codable.

has anyone an idea how I could sort the encoded message like I need?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with JSONEncoder, unfortunately. That's the problem with bad API.
One possible workaround is to use key placeholders, e.g. `keyA`, `keyB`, `keyC`, let them sort them alphabetically and then just replace them using a dictionary in the resulting JSON.

Comment: Ok, as I thought. Thanks for the reply and the suggested workaround, I will try it out.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!