# How to make json keys as a special order in Swift JSONEncoder?

Tags: json, swift, jsonencoder, jsonencode

I need make a request to a server of an open API. The rule of the open API asked json parameter must make keys as a special order(not the A-Z order nor Z-A order).

```swift
struct Req : Encodable {
    let SourceText: String
    let Target: String
    let Source: String
    let ProjectId: Int = 0
}
```

What I want is:

```json
{"SourceText":"你好","Source":"zh","Target":"en","ProjectId":0}
```

But the encoded json is:

```json
{"ProjectId":0,"Source":"zh","SourceText":"你好","Target":"en"}
```

Comment: That's a bad API though... I'm afraid you need to create a custom JSONEncoder.

Comment: Since the code is open, you could mimic that https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/de5f7edc3040057717f7da0ba875df04d3dc3e9e/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L1012 You could put in `userInfo` the keys order you want, and replicate it when writing.

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition, hence most JSON encoders/decoders don't actually support ordered encoding/decoding. If your API relies on a fixed order of a dictionary, it is a bad API and should be changed.

Comment: Or create the json string manually

Comment: I tried a json string, and send the request with alamofire with no encoders, it gives me an error:
`failure(Alamofire.AFError.parameterEncoderFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ParameterEncoderFailureReason.encoderFailed(error: Alamofire.URLEncodedFormEncoder.Error.invalidRootObject("string(\"{\\\"SourceText\\\":\\\"你好\\\",\\\"Source\\\":\\\"zh\\\",\\\"Target\\\":\\\"en\\\",\\\"ProjectId\\\":0}\")"))))`

Comment: You can use an OrderedDictionary. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76344268/2974621

Answer (score 0):

With JSONEncoder i think that isn't possible.

One possible workaround is to use key placeholders, e.g. keyA, keyB, keyC, let them sort them alphabetically and then just replace them using a dictionary in the resulting JSON [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198594/swift-jsonencoder-element-order)
I hope is helpful.

However, JSON is:

> "An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array."

[RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround here that is ok if you don't have to many properties or custom types is to build a string containing the json and then convert it to `Data`

```
extension Req {
    var jsonString: String {
        String(format: #"{""SourceText": "%@, "Source": %@, "Target": %@, "ProjectId": %d}"#,
               SourceText, Source, Target, ProjectId)
    }
}
```

or directly returning `Data?`

```
extension Req {
    var json: Data? {
        String(format: #"{""SourceText": "%@, "Source": %@, "Target": %@, "ProjectId": %d}"#,
               SourceText, Source, Target, ProjectId).data(using: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set this as Alamofire parameters, and what kind of encoder should I use?

Comment: Use the second variant or convert to Data yourself,